# How to update redux state using onChange with React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React Redux and want to be able to change the title and description of a post, using the onChange method. When only using React the way you would do this is that you keep an useState which you change whenever a change occurs, but I can't seem to get it to work with using redux in react. Instead of the state changing the original title, and description remains and cannot be changed.

From what I have read the basic idea is to have a listener on the input (onChange, usually) and have that fire a redux action. You then have the action tell the reducer to make the change to the store.

I have tried doing this, but could make it work correctly. What am I doing wrong and how do you solve it? I'm also wondering how do I specify that I want to change either title or description when using onChange, or do I simply send everything in post each time a change occurs?

This is what the redux state looks like when entering a post:

```
{
  auth: {
    isSignedIn: true,
    user: {
      id: '624481f22566374c138cf974',
      username: 'obiwan',}
  },
  posts: {
    '62448632b87b223847eaafde': {
      _id: '62448632b87b223847eaafde',
      title: 'hellothere',
      desc: 'its been a long time since I heard that name...',
      username: 'vorbrodt',
      email: 'example@gmail.com',
      categories: [],
      createdAt: '2022-03-30T16:32:50.158Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-03-30T16:32:50.158Z',
      __v: 0
    }
  },
}
```

Here is where the onChange happens.
**Post.js**

```
import { getPostById, editPost } from "../actions";

const Post = ({ getPostById, editPost, username }) => {
  const [updateMode, setUpdateMode] = useState(false);
  let { id } = useParams();
  let post = useSelector((state) => state.posts[id]);


  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    try {
      editPost(e.target.value);
    } catch (err) {}
  };

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post-wrapper">
      {updateMode ? (
        <input
          type="text"
          value={post.title}
          className="post-title-input"
          autoFocus
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
        />
      ) : (
        <h1 className="post-title">
          {post.title}
        </h1>
      )}
      <div className="desc-area">
        {updateMode ? (
          <textarea
            className="post-desc-input"
            value={post.desc}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
          />
        ) : (
          <p className="post-desc">{post.desc}</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { username: state.auth.user.username }; 
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPostById, editPost })(Post);
```

Here is the action creator:

```
//edit post in redux state
const editPost = (postValues) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: EDIT_POST, payload: postValues });
};
```

And here is the reducer which is suppose to change the state.
**postReducer.js**

```
import _ from "lodash";

import { GET_POSTS, GET_POST, CREATE_POST, EDIT_POST } from "../actions/types";

function postReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_POSTS:
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, "_id") };
    case GET_POST:
      return { ...state, [action.payload._id]: action.payload };
    case CREATE_POST:
      return { ...state, [action.payload._id]: action.payload };
    case EDIT_POST:
      //here the change should occur, not sure how to specify if title or desc should 
      //change
      return { ...state, [action.payload._id]: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default postReducer;
```

Comment: You could achieve it by giving key of input fields to redux action. `const editPost = (postValues, key) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: EDIT_POST, payload: { value: postValues, key // title or description } });
};`

Answer (score 0):

Hey there something like this should be of help

```
const handleInputChange = (e, key, id) => {
    try {
      editPost({ [key]: e.target.value, id });
    } catch (err) {}
  };
```

Usage

```
           <textarea
            className="post-desc-input"
            value={post.desc}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, "title", post.id)}
          />
```

action

```
const editPost = (postValues) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: EDIT_POST, payload: postValues });
};
```

Reducer

```
    case EDIT_POST:
//here we destructure the id and return the data without the id cause we //need it below
const {id, ...newData} = action.payload
const indexToUpdate = state.posts.find(post => post.id === id)
const newPostsData = [...state.posts]

//Here we update the actual object and its property that is in the state at //the specific value
newPostsData[indexToUpdate] = {...newPostData[indexToUpdate], {...newData}
          return { ...state, posts: newPostsData};
```

Comment: This is to just be able to help you with the logic how you intend to structure your data is entirely up to you and then you would just need to update your logic accordingly